# html select list : chained and filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I have 2 select option list, they are chained with this method : [Chained Select List](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained)

I have added an input in order to filter all values in these 2 select with this method: [Input Filter Select List](http://www.lessanvaezi.com/filter-select-list-options/)

When a user type a word in the input, there are two case :

1/ If the user click on a word in the first list : it will show values possible in the second list

2/ If the user click on a word in the second list : it must show/highlight the 'parent' in the first list..

I don't know how to achieve the second case..

I'm open minded to every solution :)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you have to do it using javascript..
There are two ways to do this

1. maintain an array of parents for the options available in the second list. get the values from array using arrday indexes of the select value in the list. use onChange() event on second list and populate the parent in the first list.
2. for second list, provide the option value to its parent.. i.e. when user selects an option in second list... as value it should return its parent... we will be able to populate the vallue in first list accordingly. please be aware that in this case it is overrding the actual values in second list.

Comment: thanks for your help, I was trying your solution when I saw this : [link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/change-select-box-option-based-on-another-select-box-on-page), it seems more easy :)